# Django Model With Multiple Classes

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm writing my first Django app and want to create a header model which has several different classes in it.

Code:

```
class Meta(models.Model):
    meta_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=500) 
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    page_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Javascript(models.Model):
    page_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.BooleanField()

class Javascript_resources(models.Model):
    page_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.BooleanField() #whether or not these are live/local

class Style_sheets(models.Model):
    page_id = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    resource_type = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    status = models.BooleanField()
```

How could I create a function in the model to return an object that has the correct meta object, style_sheets object, javascript object etc..

Comment: What is the question? Is this 'Would it be best to create a view...'? Or you have a problem to create the mentioned object?

Comment: Both, I'm not sure how to combine the model. How could I create a single method that would return this object, whether it be in the view or model?

Comment: Are you sure that page_id exists for all of the objects if it exists for one any?

Comment: page_id is always given. I would always pass a unique page id to this header app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for this problem, in my case, ended up looking like this:

I like to store the related files in a database for several reasons. In my settings file I have a status setting that allows me to control the entire site's header. I have certain files that are live/local only and some that are resources. For instance, I used less css locally but compile it for the live site. When I change this variable, this automatically changes my headers by querying the database for the proper files. I also check the files exist because it can be very frustrating to debug when a css/js file doesn't load properly! Its a bit overkill but will be used for many sites.

```
from models import *
```

from django.conf import settings
from os import path # could also be written as import os.path

class Resources(object):

```
status = True
page_id = ""


# META INFORMATION
meta_keywords = ""
meta_description = ""
page_title = ""
favicon = ""

# RESOURCES
javascript_resources = []
javascript_files = []
style_sheets = []

def __init__(self, page_id = "home"):
    self.page_id = page_id.lower()
    self.get_status()
    self.get_meta()
    self.get_javascript()
    self.get_style_sheets()

def get_status(self):
    status = settings.SITE_STATUS

    if(status != "live"):
        self.status = False
    else:
        self.status = True


def get_meta(self):
    current = Meta.objects.get(page_id = self.page_id)
    self.meta_keywords = current.meta_keywords
    self.meta_description = current.meta_description
    self.page_title = current.page_title
    self.favicon = current.favicon

# this function will set all of the proper javascript lists and validate all files!
def get_javascript(self):


    javascript_list = Javascript.objects.filter(Q(page_id = "all") | Q(page_id = self.page_id)).filter(status = self.status)
    javascript_resources_list = Javascript_resources.objects.filter(Q(page_id = "all") | Q(page_id = self.page_id)).filter(status = self.status)

    #now evaulate the javascript
    if len(javascript_list) > 0:
        for resource in javascript_list:
            file_name = resource.url

            if self.exists(file_name):
                self.javascript_files.append(file_name)

    if len(javascript_resources_list) > 0:
        for resource in javascript_resources_list:
            file_name = resource.url

            if self.exists(file_name):
                self.javascript_resources.append(file_name)


def get_style_sheets(self):

    style_sheet_list = Style_sheets.objects.filter(Q(page_id = "all") | Q(page_id = self.page_id)).filter(status = self.status)


    if len(style_sheet_list) > 0:
        for resource in style_sheet_list:
            file_name = resource.url
            file_type = resource.file_type

            if self.exists(file_name):
                style_sheet = []
                style_sheet.append(file_type)
                style_sheet.append(file_name)

                self.style_sheets.append(style_sheet)

def exists(self, file_name):

    url = settings.STATIC_URL + file_name

    status = False

    if  path.exists(url):
        status = True

    return status
```

Comment: this would also be very convenient for compiling javascript. I'm going to write a python program to query the correct local js files for a page and compile them into one file for the live site.

Answer (score 2):

If there are different models you can't create the such method in one any model because the one model does not know about other models. It's an incapsulation.

I think it's normal to make a dict union of the objects the more you have different fields with the same name ('status').

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
...
def your_view( request ):
    t = loader.get_template( your_template )
    if 'page_id' in request.REQUEST:
        page_id = request.REQUEST[ 'page_id' ]       

        all_objs = { 'metas': Meta.objects.filter( page_id = page_id ),
                        'javascripts': Javascript.objects.filter( page_id = page_id ),
                        'javascript_resources': JavascriptResources.objects.filter( page_id = page_id ),
                        'style_sheets': StyleSheets.objects.filter( page_id = page_id ) }
        c = RequestContext( request, all_objs )
    else:
        c = RequestContext( request )

    return HttpResponse( t.render(c), content_type = 'text/html' )
```

Then in template you could iterate over them (an example for javascripts):

```
{% for javascript in javascripts %}
    {% if javascript.status %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Details of implemetation depends on if objects  with a custom page_id exist. May be you should check the existance.

Answer (score 1):

As all your models seem to refer to a page you should probably create a `Page` model and replace your `page_ids` with `ForeignKeys`:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()


class Meta(models.Model):
    meta_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=500) 
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
```

Nonetheless I think having all the parts of the page in seperate models (=tables in the database) is somehow overkill, though I do not exactly know your use case. Another possibilities would be combining these models in one using multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you define your database structure in models.py and reserve most functions in views.py. It seems like you are trying to create a function that gets you a record based on certain parameters. For that, define a function in views.py that gets the related records from your tables and returns it to you.

I suggest you go through the Django tutorial found here, especially page 3.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: Why 2 same answers? Please delete one of your answers.

Comment: This makes sense, just one question. Is it possible to have the view just return the object that I want? That way I can use this app in other apps and just call that view? Is this a good practice?

Comment: @JonMorehouse Yes its possible for a view to just return one object. IMO its the best way to retrieve a singular record.